# why np.cos returns erroneous values?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm debugging my python program.

I have `np.cos(param_t_10[0])` returns `5.9168e-06` where `param_t_10[0] == tensor(-1.5708)`

If I print `np.cos(-1.5708)` I get `-3.673205103346574e-06` which is the correct value.

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make a reproducible example.

Comment: I would always rather use the made in tensorflow / pytorch cosine function rather than numpy one when working with tensors. Maybe trying them will give a different result.

Comment: Tensorflow often uses 32-bit floats by default. That's about 7 significant figures in terms of precision https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format, so you should be worried when you get down to comparing such small quantities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to compare floating point numbers by `==`. E.g., this may give different result depending on your number representation. Additionally, the conversion from a tensor to a float/numpy object can have side effects (you could `print(param_t_10[0])` and `print(float(param_t_10[0]))` for a first check).

Comment: This is probably the source of the problem. Thank you.